# Get rid of 'One or more items failed to play. Check the log file for details.' in XBMC

Tags: streaming, kodi

the question is simple.
How to get rid of this dialog message in Kodi (xmbc)?

The developers refuse to fix this, and this message happens every time when the streaming playlist contains a few unavailable links or Kodi cannot read the stream. I reviewed the source code and it seems they have two settings for retry count and timeout.

It's impossible to not have this dialog on a screen and have Kodi responsive. Either you will loop in this playlist forever if those settings are set to high numbers or you will get that ugly dialog.

I listen to the web radio and have a few urls in a playlist. Sometimes my internet goes down, other times the web radios are unavailable. Every such time Kodi throws this dialog message and the only way to remove the message is to click "Enter" or "OK" with a mouse. It's a dialog box and it has the attribute "always on top".

Most players allow for the setting to not show the error messages like that if the user prefers it to be written to error log and not block anything in gui. (Best example is VLC: it shows a similar window WITH a checkbox below: "Hide future errors") Not xmbc. There were many complaints on the xmbc support site, but the developer's answer is "we not gonna fix that, love it or leave it".

Could you recommend the fix? Is the source code editing the only way?

Comment: It does indeed sound like something that would have to be fixed in the source code. Since Kodi is open source this should be easy enough to do.

Comment: @Ramhound What bothers me is that I will need to do it every time Kodi has a new minor (and major) release in case I want to get updates.

Comment: If there is no option to disable the messages then your only choice is to modify the source code so there is and/or make the error messages silent.

Comment: By the way, the question is indeed about "is there a workaround" to disable the message. For example, the python script that gets an event can monitor Kodi and whenever such event occurs, send <Enter>. So I basically ask if someone had solved this problem already and how.